# Question re meaning of term ‘further’ in phrase, ‘In a further preferred embodiment, …’

Tags: translation, patentese, translating, dutch

Is the phrase ‘In a **further** preferred embodiment’ synonymous with ‘In a **more** preferred embodiment’?

That is, is ‘further’ being used to mean:

(#1)  yet another / additional / other

or

(#2) more

?

I'm asking because I’m a patent translator, working from Dutch into English and vice versa, and this phrase often causes some confusion when translating it into Dutch.

Following the above numbering, there would seem to be two ways of translating this phrase:

(#1) ‘In een verdere voorkeursuitvoering(svorm)’ [= yet another / additional / other]

(#2) ‘In een verder te verkiezen uitvoeringsvorm’ [= more]
(#2) ‘In een meer geprefereerde uitvoeringsvorm’ [= more]

Comment: The same question applies to the phrases: "In a preferred form, … ", "In a further preferred form, …".

Answer (score 1):

I lean towards option #1: yet another / additional / other. In principle one should not describe what embodiment more preferred over others.

Comment: The question is about translation. I do not like "preferred" either but if it is in the original it must be in the translated - or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Yes, you are right. What I meant is that, in principle, a patent attorney drafting a patent application would not state what is more preferable over other alternatives, and in that sense "further" would be construed as meaning "another". I likewise do not like the term "preferred" and it should be avoided, but even if that term is used, I would not expect the patent drafter to say "even more preferred".

Comment: Now I understand the point. I agree.